# Renderscript Intrinsics documentation

Tags: android, intrinsics, renderscript

I use the Renderscript ScriptIntrinsicBlur, which which works great and saves my app a lot of calculation time. However, I was looking for a kind of a user guide and documentation of these very useful Renderscript Intrinsic functions but found almost nothing, except some high level technical info on the developer site. For example:

> how is the blur radius of ScriptIntrinsicBlur defined? I assume it must some cut-off of the gaussian Sigma in relation to the kernel size (e.g. 99%), but I didn't find anything on that.
>   also I would be interested in the histogram function, e.g. in order to apply them for histogram-matching of two Pictures. But I found little on that. 
>   how exactly are the types U8_4, U8_3, U8_2, U8 defined? And what type would be most efficient for Gray-Value Pictures?

Thanks for any Feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about the Gaussian Sigma here, but the source code is available online (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/master/cpu_ref/rsCpuIntrinsicBlur.cpp). Note that GPGPU drivers are free to reimplement this slightly differently too.

As far as the U8 stuff goes, those are just the underlying Element types. U8 means a single unsigned char. U8_2 is a 2-wide vector of unsigned chars. U8_3 and U8_4 are similarly 3 and 4 wide vectors of unsigned chars. For many image processing tasks, U8_4 is the underlying type (as in RGBA_8888, which is 4 8-bit values for red, green, blue, alpha).

Comment: Thank you Stephen for that explanation. From the code I see that they use: sigma = 0.4f * mRadius + 0.6f; meaning that the gauss-cutoff is about 5% for sigma=3 (i.e. radius = 6) and goes towards 1% for sigma >=7 (i.e. radius >= 16), which makes sense. Still trying to understand Renderscript in order to use it myself. Of course, examples help, but a  20-30 page basic introduction would make it much easier to understand and save a lot of time.

Comment: We are working on some RS tutorials that we hope to share soon, but I certainly understand it is hard to learn without some extra guidance. Fortunately, we answer a lot of stackoverflow questions, too, so please post more if you run into problems.

Comment: The point is, that even trivial basics can just be found out by guessing and/or try and error, and that's rather frustrating. For example I want to set-up a filter with In-Allocation = Bitmap (i.e. U8_4) and Out-Allocation = float vector float3, in order to consider also negative values, as e.g. with a Sobel Filter. It takes too long in order to find out such things and even if I find some analogue example, I cannot really trust, if I don't understand even the basic principles.